# regex "split by commas Saving an inner comma"

Tags: regex

I am  building  a report  of   active  directory  distribution groups and  i  want to get  the  `ManageBy`  returned  as  `Aviles Gutierrez, Abraham` instead  of the  whole DN

```
CN=Aviles Gutierrez\, Abraham,OU=Users,OU=TremecTJ,OU=Mexico,DC=Tremec,DC=local
```

Im  trying to create  a custom  attribute   extracting  the  Managedby  with the following regex:  `'^CN=|\\,,.*'`. As result  i  only get  `Aviles Gutierrez`

How can  my regex  skip that internal  comma  after the backslash  `\,`  and  get  'Aviles Gutierrez, Abraham'

Answer (score 0):

You can not really "skip" a comma in a single match. But you can capture the part with a capture group using:

```
^CN=(.*?)(?:,[A-Z]+=|$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qR9zkG/1)

That will capture `Aviles Gutierrez\, Abraham` and then you can replace the `\,` with `,` if you want.

For a match only, and if lookarounds are supported:

```
(?<=^CN=).*?(?=,[A-Z]+=|$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZVihbP/1)